# Why Wordpress dont't see my js function when i try to inner it to the site?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I am fixing bugs in WordPress first time. I have a menu when it is the mobile version of cite it creating into the burger menu and is hidden at the right of the screen because has opacity: 0 and transform: translate(100%,0). I create a simply js function that must create style opacity: 1 and transform: 0, but I don't know where I need to put this function. Help me please!!!

This image have onClick Event:

```
<span id="myBtn" class="btn-menu js-menu"><i></i></span>
```

Here is my js function:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
      document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() { 
        document.getElementById("lestOfItem").style.opacity = 1;
        document.getElementById("lestOfItem").style.transform = "inherit";
        document.getElementById("lestOfItem").style.width = "100%";
        document.getElementById("lestOfItem").style.textAlign = "center";
    });
</script>
```

Menu which must be opened when i click into the image:

```
 <ul id="lestOfItem" class="">
 ---items--- 
</ul>
```

Comment: Please share more details, like your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: I try to function in some functions.php or other files, but I don't understand how i need use them
Also, when I put my script in the header or footer like in the default HTML file, HTML after rendering didn't see it. I mean if i check page source my function just disappear

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: you need to learn how to import your own javascript into wordpress first. there's a lot of ways to do it. just googled it now here's the first result https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-add-custom-javascript-to-your-wordpress-site--cms-34368

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you in the right direction: [Add Custom JavaScript into your WordPress Site][1]

Source: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/custom-js/

In some situations, you may need to add custom JavaScript to your site. Normally, this would involve modifying your theme files.

However, there is a less intrusive alternative. "Header and Footer Scripts" is a plugin to add custom JavaScript to WordPress without modifying your theme.

1. Install the plugin:
2. Log in to your WordPress site.
3. Go to Plugins > Add new
4. Search for "Header and Footer Scripts".
5. Click "Install Now" and activate the plugin.
6. Custom JavaScript into WordPress

Option #1.

1. Upload a custom JavaScript file
2. Save your custom JavaScript code into a file with the .js format
3. Upload it into your site to this folder:

> wp-content/themes/your-theme/js/

4. Go to Settings > Header and Footer Scripts.

Now you have two options to load the file:

- Scripts in header (load inside head tag)
- Scripts in footer (load before closing body tag)
- Use the location that match better your needs using this syntax as example:

  <
  script src="http://www.yoursite.any/wp-content/themes/your-theme/js/file.js" >

  < /script>

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer instead of linking to external ressources

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your js (script) code in footer.php in your theme (before `</body>`)

Comment: Only before body? Without any functions.php or PHP hooks?
I will try, ty

Comment: yeah. its not a good way of adding js though. since you have only few lines of code. its fine.

OR you can use separate js file and use wp hook see (Combining Enqueue Functions ) section : https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript